# Will I be able to use Clojure functions as Lambdas in Java 8?

Tags: java, clojure, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

I use a number of libraries in Clojure that produce higher order functions that conform to the "[clojure.lang.IFn](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IFn.java)" interface.

It has multiple arity overloads, I.e. the interface looks something like:

```
public interface IFn extends Callable, Runnable{
  public Object invoke() ;
  public Object invoke(Object arg1) ;
  public Object invoke(Object arg1, Object arg2) ;
  public Object invoke(Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3) ;
  .... etc.
  public Object applyTo(ISeq arglist) ;
}
```

Will I be able to use objects of this type directly in Java 8 as callable lambda functions?

Comment: IIRC, Java 8 does not let you "call" lambda functions in any new way; it only provides new ways to _create_ lambda functions, which must be single-function interfaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you mean, use objects of this type as callable lambdas?

In *very simple* cases, Java 8 lambdas *can be thought as* syntactic sugar + some type inference for anonymous classes for certain type of interfaces, namely *functional interfaces* [[1]](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html):

> The interface ActionListener, used above, has just one method. Many
>   common callback interfaces have this property, such as Runnable and
>   Comparator. We'll give all interfaces that have just one method a
>   name: functional interfaces.

Remark: lambdas are really not just a sugar; internally they are implemented differently than anonymous classes, and there are also some semantic differences; see [this excellent answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/181743) on ProgrammersExchange for more on this matter. However, this is not really important in context of this question and answer.

Anywhere where a value of some functional interface is expected (method argument, local variable, field declaration etc.) it will be possible to use short syntax for creating an entity resemling anonymous class implementing this method, that is, a lambda expression:

```
Runnable r = () -> {
    System.out.println("Hi");
};
// Equivalent to
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
};

public interface Function<F, T> {
    T call(F arg);
}

Function<String, char[]> c = s -> ("<" + s + ">").toCharArray();
// Equivalent to
Function<String, char[]> c = new Function<>() {
    public char[] call(String s) {
        return ("<" + s + ">").toCharArray();
    }
};
```

So your question can only be interpreted in the following way: is it possible to create objects of type `IFn` using Java 8 lambda syntax?

The answer is no. Lambda syntax is possible only with functional interfaces. `clojure.lang.IFn` is not a functional interface because it contains much more than single method, so it won't be possible to do something like

```
IFn f = (String s) -> s.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: The idea that Java 8 lambdas are syntactic sugar on anonymous inner classes is a meme that just won't go away. See the answers to this question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/177879/type-inference-in-java-8, for an explanation of why it is wrong. This is clearly going to be a frequent question; I'll put an answer on the Lambda FAQ (http://www.lambdafaq.org)

Comment: @MauriceNaftalin, thank you, I should have been reading lambda spec more thoroughly. I'm adding a notice about it.

Comment: My interpretation of the question is the opposite of what you've got here. I think he wants to pass clojure functions, which are objects which implement the interface IFn, to java functions that expect an object implementing their single function interface. The answer I suspect is no.

Answer (score 2):

No, it seems you can not use clojure functions as if they are also valid java lambdas. Clojure's IFn does not conform to java's "lambda" functional interfaces as defined.