# How to pass in a parameter to a static method in Clojure?

Tags: java, clojure, rapidoid

I have the following method:

```
package com.streambright.http.handlers;

import org.rapidoid.http.Req;
import org.rapidoid.u.U;

import java.util.Map;

public class EchoHandler {

    public static Map<String, String> handleEcho(Req req) {
        return U.map(req.headers());
    }
}
```

When I use it from have it is perfectly fine:

```
On.get("/echo").managed(false).json(EchoHandler::handleEcho);
```

However when I try to do the same in Clojure it fails with wrong number of arguments.

Handler:

```
(ns s.echo-http-handler
  (:import
    [org.rapidoid.http  Req ]
    [org.rapidoid.u     U   ] )
  (:gen-class
    :methods [^:static [handler [org.rapidoid.http.Req] java.util.Map]]))

(defn -handler
  [Req req]
  (U/map (.headers req)))
```

When I start the server:

```
(ns s.http
  (:require
    [s.echo-http-handler  :as echo    ] )
  (:import
    [org.rapidoid.config  Conf  ]
    [org.rapidoid.setup   On    ] ) )

    (defn start
      []
      (set-http-params!)
      (.json (.managed (On/get "/echo") false) echo/-handler))
```

It starts up and throws the following error:

```
clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (0) passed to: echo-http-handler/-handler
```

How do I pass in the req to the function in Clojure?

Comment: Are you sure this is a Clojure issue? I'm not familiar with Rapidoid, but it seems as though *it* isn't passing the required argument. What decides if the `json` method passes an argument to the function given to it? From a quick search, is seems as though it can accept both 0 and 1 arity functions.

Comment: This boils down to be able to port the (Req req, Resp resp) -> {return ....} code from Java to Clojure. That I am no sure how to do.

Comment: It seems it is not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452568/will-i-be-able-to-use-clojure-functions-as-lambdas-in-java-8

Comment: But again, what decides the arity of the callback given to 'json`? It's the library that's passing the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: And to make use of Functional Interfaces in Clojure, you can use `reify` to create an object that implements the interface. You just can't use the terse anonymous function syntax unfortunately.

Comment: Yes. I am not sure how to rewrite () -> {} to a way that Clojure handles.

Comment: What functional inferface does Rapidoid use? I can write an answer if I know that. Their mobile site loads horribly on mobile, so I'm having a hard time poking around their site.

Comment: I was under able to find the name of the functional interface used. The answer to your question though is to use `reify` like I said and create an object that implements the needed interface.

Comment: This is where .json is defined: https://github.com/rapidoid/rapidoid/blob/master/rapidoid-http-server/src/main/java/org/rapidoid/setup/OnRoute.java#L175

Comment: I'll take a look on my next break if no one else has answered by then. Should be a quick write-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the problem is with how it's handeling Clojure functions, the following should work:

```
(ns your-namespace
  (:import [org.rapidoid.http Req ReqHandler]))

; Helper to create an object that implements ReqHandler
(defn makeReqHandler [f]
  ; Basically "new ReqHandler {...}"
  (reify ReqHandler
    (execute [this, ^Req req] (f req))
```

This function takes a Clojure function, and uses it to create an object that implements `ReqHandler`. I think the problem was it was assuming (for some reason) that you wanted the 0-arity overload of `.json`, when you really wanted the overload that passes an argument to the callback. This helper should prevent that confusion.

Then use as:

```
(let [handler (makeReqHandler echo/-handler)]
  (.json (.managed (On/get "/echo") false) handler)))
```

Although that could also be written as:

```
(->  (On/get "/echo")
     (.managed false)
     (.json handler))
```

Or even with the handler inlined to show that it's still possible using a wrapper function to use terse anonymous function syntax:

```
(->  (On/get "/echo")
     (.managed false)
     (.json (makeReqHandler #(U/map (.headers %)))))
```

Which is arguably a lot more readable. Because `this` is always implicitly the first argument when using Java interop, `doto` and `->` are great at getting rid of nesting.

Comment: Getting close! :) error = java.lang.AbstractMethodError: s.http_handlers$create_request_handler$reify__49.execute(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Comment: @Istvan Is there any chance you imported the wrong ReqHandler? ReqHandler is an interface, so it shouldn't have anything to do with abstract methods. I'll update the code with the imports.

Comment: @Istvan I'll update the imports when I get on a full computer. You *must* be importing the wrong files. There are no abstract classes involved, so that error doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Istvan And are you using the latest version of the library? If they switched from using abstract classes to interfaces, and you're still using the version that uses abstract classes, this will fail with that error. Try updating the library and running it again.

Comment: I am using the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

I used to play with rapidoid a bit. Your mistake here is you are trying to pass just a Clojure function as a handler. Instead, it should be an instance of `ReqHandler` Java class. So you need to create an instance of anonymous class that extends it.

Wrong:

```
(defn -handler
  [Req req]
  (U/map (.headers req)))
```

Correct:

```
(reify ReqHandler
 (execute [this, ^Req req]
   ;; here, access req's fields to write the body or headers
   ))
```